# Need to SELECT a row even when the value doesn't exist

Tags: sql

I need to get the maximum score for a particular game_id, for each user:

table 'scores'

```
----------------------
|uid |game_id |score |
----------------------
|1   |0       |0     |
|2   |0       |0     |
|1   |0       |1     |
|1   |0       |2     |
|2   |1       |0     |
|2   |1       |3     |
|2   |1       |5     |
----------------------
```

I need this output (for game_id = 1):

```
-------------
|uid |score |
-------------
|1   |      |
|2   |5     |
-------------
```

As you can see, user 1 doesn't have an entry for game_id 1, but I need him to be returned still...

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried writing a query yourself?

Comment: It's not such a bad question. It's sensibly scoped and well explained. No need for the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select uid, max(case when game_id = 1 then score end) as game1max
from scores
group by uid;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a self-referencing left-join:

```
SELECT s1.uid, MAX(s2.score) MaxSCore
FROM scores s1
LEFT JOIN scores s2
  ON s1.uid = s2.uid
     AND game_id = 1
GROUP BY s1.uid
```

or a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    s1.uid, 
    (SELECT MAX(s2.score) 
     FROM scores s2
     WHERE s1.uid = s2.uid
        AND game_id = 1) MaxScore
FROM scores s1
```